# How to releasing dual-platform software without Mac OS 'grep -P'?

Tags: design, software

I have some open source software I'm planning on releasing which invokes `grep -nP` via the command line. (Yes, this is arguably a terrible decision.)

The problem I'm running into is that while this runs great on Linux, my functions fail on Mac OS, because `grep -P` doesn't work as expect on Mac. I'll receive the following error:

```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/35848

In the above link, Homebrew apparently installs this as "ggrep".

Given this problem, how could I release this software such that it works on both platforms?

Request modifying "grep" in the user's bash profile? Requirement Mac OS users to fiddle with the source code?

Any help with this grep "NP" problem appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When writing cross-platform code, you have two choices:

- target a common standard supported by all targeted platforms, or
- write separate code for each targeted platform.

The common standard for Unix systems is POSIX. This standard mandates which features for certain command line tools must be available, [including `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). Note that POSIX grep does not provide PCRE regexes, but does support “extended” regular expressions. These may be sufficient for your use case, but have a slightly different syntax and far less features.

When doing development on a Linux system, it is easy to accidentally depend on the various extensions in the GNU utilities. It is therefore important that you also test on systems that don't have GNU utilities installed, and read the standard to get to know which features are guaranteed.

As an alternative, you can require the GNU utilities as a dependency of your software, but this may unnecessarily inconvenience users. It may also be desirable to depend on other non-POSIX software, such as a widely available programming language. Perl and Python are widely pre-installed or easily available for many Unix systems. Perl makes a top-notch regex engine easily available to command-line programs.

It is not necessary that the user aliases the GNU tools to a specific name if you make your software sufficiently configurable, e.g. through an environment variable. In this case, I would resolve the grep utility through this mechanism:

```
if an env variable GREP exists:
  use the env variable GREP
if not on Linux:
  if a ggrep utility exists:
    use the ggrep utility
use the grep utility
```

I have used similar strategies when writing cross-platform shell scripts for Linux and Solaris, which (like macOS) only has the GNU utilities available as a separate install.